# SSL certificate error in Python requests module, but not in VBA

Tags: python, vba, http, ssl, python-requests

I am trying to send a request to company's intranet page like below:

```
import requests

http_proxy  = 'some_proxy1'
https_proxy = 'some_proxy2'
URL = 'some_url'


proxyDict = { 
              "http"  : some_proxy1, 
              "https" : some_proxy2
            }

response = requests.get(some_url, proxies=proxyDict, verify=False)
```

Even though `verify` is set to `False`, I get

`SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'sslv3 alert bad certificate')],)",)`

The code works fine for external pages.

Strangely, I tried same request (but without proxies) through VBA, and it works:

```
Sub request()

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
URL = "some_url"
objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
objHTTP.send
Debug.Print objHTTP.responseText

end sub
```

Is there anything I can do to make the Python code work?

And why does VBA not have a problem with SSL certificate? Is it because it somehow knows it beforehand - since it is native to Windows - and no verification is required?

Answer (score 2):

> SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'sslv3 alert bad certificate')],)",)

This likely means that the server is expecting you to authenticate with a client certificate. My guess is that the specific certificate is in the Windows certificate store and will be automatically used by your VB script the same as it is used automatically by the browser. Only, Python does not use the windows certificate store. This mean you need to somehow extract the specific certificates from the store and use these explicitly as client certificates in your Python program [as documented](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#client-side-certificates).

Comment: Thanks Steffen, this was my guess as well. However, I tried exporting the certificate in all available formats and used it with requests as per documentation: `cert=cert_path`, but I get `Error: [('PEM routines', 'PEM_read_bio', 'no start line'), ('SSL routines', 'SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file', 'PEM lib')]. ` Do you possibly know why?

Comment: @barciewicz: it looks like the format is wrong. It should be a PEM file with both certificate and subject, i.e. should be base64 with delimiters like `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`.

Comment: Thanks Steffen. The format is .cer, so it is a PEM file. However, while exporting the certificate, the option to export private key as well is not available. So there is BEGIN CERTIFICATE in the file, but no BEGIN PRIVATE KEY. Do you think this might be the issue?

Comment: @barciewicz: To authenticate with a client certificate you need both the (public) certificate and the private key.